# Get all messages from Outlook API

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I'm consuming the Outlook API, attempting to access all messages from an inbox which contains ~45,000 messages (and other folders such as Sent Items).

The main request I'm making is to https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages. If I add ?$count=true, the `"@odata.count"` value is returned as -1.

I can add $top=500 to the request which gives me 500 messages returned and an `"@odata.nextLink"`, but if I pass $top=5000, there's no `"@odata.nextLink"` which I'd expect to see.

A few particular questions here if anyone can help:

1. Is this the best way to try and get all the messages out of all folders?
2. Is there a reason count would be returning -1, and is there a way to get an accurate figure of the number of messages returned?
3. Is there a maximum $top size I need to pass to get a valid request back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, but understand it includes Drafts, Deleted Items, and Sent Items in addition to all of the other mail folders.
2. This is a known issue with `/me/messages`. Basically the way that `/me/messages` gives all messages across all folders is by using a search folder, which dynamically updates. The API doesn't report accurate counts for search folders (usually just returns -1).
3. The highest `$top` should be 1000.

Comment: Thanks very much, and for jumping in to this. I do seem to have got round this by sticking a date search filter in, it's then paging through properly.