# How do I get the count of messages in the mailbox?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have the problem with counting the messages of mailbox.
I use c# and Microsoft.Graph 1.18.0

Here is my code

```
 public async Task<long> GetItemsCountAsync(string userId)
        {
            var countOption = new QueryOption("$count", "true");

            var request = ServiceClient.Value.Users[userId].Messages.Request();
            request.QueryOptions.Add(countOption);
            var resultMessages = new List<Message>();
            var count = 0L;

            do
            {
                var messagesResult = await request.GetAsync();

                if (messagesResult.AdditionalData != null && messagesResult.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.count", out var messagesCount))
                {
                    count = (long)messagesCount;
                }

                resultMessages.AddRange(messagesResult);
                request = messagesResult.NextPageRequest;
            }
            while (request != null);

            return count;
        }
```

And I have at the end count = 1417 and resultMessages.Count = 760

Did I miss something?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is fine with the provided example. It appears `$count` for [`List messages` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) could not be trusted here since API does not return accurate count for  messages from a specified search folder (refer, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784203/1375553) for a more details).

To get messages count [`List mailFolders` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) could be utilized instead:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders?$select=totalItemCount
```

where `totalItemCount` represents the number of items in the mail folder.

**C# example**

```
var folders = await graphClient.Users[userId].MailFolders.Request().Select(f =>f.TotalItemCount).GetAsync();
var totalMessagesCount = folders.Sum(folder => folder.TotalItemCount);
```