# Azure Graph API - Include total email count in get messages service call

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm able to retrieve the first 25 emails from a specific email inbox using below Graph API url.

> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<EMAIL_ADDRESS>/mailFolders/inbox/messages/?$skip=0&top=25&count=true`

As per Azure Graph API documentation, we can include total email message count in given folder(e.g., Inbox) by including `count=true` flag.

The count returned in response is inaccurate and sometimes it returns negative values. What is the correct way to get total count along with the response?

Answer (score 1):

Several minutes ago, I got `-1` as the value of `@odata.count` when calling the same api.

However, it works now. You can try it again.

[image]

Comment: Recent service calls returned a positive number. But still the count is not accurate. If I move one of the email from inbox, it is supposed to return **previous total-1**. But it still shows the previous count.

Comment: @Joe Did you delete it locally? I just delete it from O365 portal(https://outlook.office365.com/mail/inbox). The account will change.

Comment: @Joe If you delete it from outlook desktop application. The count won't change.

Comment: Just wonder why because the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<EMAIL_ADDRESS>/mailFolders/inbox` URL gives the count correctly. I guess a bug in Azure system

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters
On the beta endpoint, the $ prefix is optional. For example, instead of $filter, you can use filter. On the v1 endpoint, the $ prefix is optional for only a subset of APIs. For simplicity, always include $ if using the v1 endpoint.

Try https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/EmailAccount/mailFolders/inbox/messages/?$skip=0&top=25&$count=true.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583079/1178375) is the stackoverflow answer you are looking for.

This will return all the folders with their TotalItemCount and unreadItemCount:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is the microsoft doc for quick reference.